# How are these hall effect sensors connected?

Tags: dc-motor, encoder, hall-effect

Trying to understand how to wire the [hall effect sensors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CYETY.png) from a car seat motor. The part # given in the image below seems to be an Allegro device. I can't figure out how to wire these. It seems pin 2 of the sensor is where you'd get the output from. However, according to this schematic, there is no way to access that pin. The Out 1 and 2 as shown in the image would be where you'd connect 5V. I need to provide a way on the driver board to connect these. Should I just provide a 3 pin terminal where you can connect Out 1 and 2 and a 5V supply next to it? Full motor specs are <s>[here](https://i.imgur.com/yeSmN3D.png) (caution: massive image)</s> shown here (this is a [scaled-down image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WllkT.jpg) of the full motor spec which is a massive TIFF file.

[image]

Comment: did you actually look at the picture you posted? .... where did you get it from?

Comment: I did, why? Came from a client who forwarded me that massive image linked in the post for the motor specs. I added the hall sensors part here.

Comment: the image is unreadable when zoomed in

Comment: I can see it fine on my browser. Here is the [link for the image](https://i.imgur.com/BXo6yQL.png).

Comment: that one is fine ... sorry, i was talking about the link to the full motor spec ... my apologies for being unclear

Comment: No worries! I've edited the post to point to a scaled-down image of the full specs.